# Get the child object of a limit(1) query on firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

#### I have this data

[image]

#### I do this query

```
firebase.database().ref(${path}/buy)
  .orderByChild('price').limitToFirst(1)
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => console.log(snapshot.val()))
```

#### And I get this result

[image]

#### Then the question is

> Is there an easy way to access the price attribute of the *one* object whose key I don't know?
> e.g. `snapshot.first().price` or `snapshot.only().price`

Simply put, I want to avoid this

```
var result = snapshot.val()
var key = Object.keys(result)[0]
var price = result[key].price
```

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

In your callback you need to handle this list by using `snapshot.forEach()`:

```
firebase.database().ref(${path}/buy)
  .orderByChild('price').limitToFirst(1)
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => { 
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          console.log(child.val());
          console.log(child.val().price);
      }) 
  })
```

Comment: Thank you Frank, however I only need the price of the one (and always only one) returned object, and I need to use the price in following code. I only consoled it to make a screenshot of it :). I need the price as a variable, so using property accessor with `Object.keys` seems as better option than `forEach`.